# FME conversion defaults to inches when all data is in meters

Tags: convert, fme-form, autocad

I regurlaly do conversions between shape, dwg, tif, and a few other formats in FME. Often, the resulting unit in dwg files is inches. I'm a bit surprised at this, since all ingoing data is in meters and also in a coordinate system defined in meters.

Is there a way to set the units in FME to make sure it's using meters in the dwg file?

This is a recent workspace I have used to create a dwg file. All data is set to Sweref99_1800 (EPSG3011), which is based on meters. The dwg file was in inches when done.

[image]

I'm guessing this is a setting for default values in Autocad, but I'm hoping I can access the setting from FME. I'm also open to alternative solutions, in case I have got something wrong! :)

Comment: Try a reprojector or a coordinateSystemSetter https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-system-setter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Insertion Scale Units?

[image: FME - Navigator - FME ACAD Writer] [image: AutoCad - Drawing Units]

Defining a template file for the DWG writer works as well.

Comment: That is probably what I want! I'll have to wait until I'm back from my holidays in august to try it though.